# Search and extract data from AS400 using IBM Domino Lotus Notes workflow

Tags: lotus-domino, ibm-midrange, lotus

I was doing a lotus notes workflow which needs to connect to my ERP system, AS400 to search and extract data into the workflow.
Any idea I can possibly do that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use DECS on the domino to connect to your AS400 using a scripted activity (or configure a sync). Therefor you need a DB2- driver installed on your Domino server. The other possibility would be to use LEI (that costs a bunch of money, but can do a lot more). The third possibility would be to use lsxcon- classes and write an Agent to get data.

A JAVA- Agent with JDBC might be possible as well (if AS400 supports access using JDBC and you have the appropriate driver).

All solutions will either need someone to code it or money to buy the licences...

If it is a "one time" or "manual" task then the DB2 driver can be installed on a Client where the agent is run manually or in a local schedule (only working if client is running).

Comment: IBM haven't made an AS/400 since what, 2000?  But even machines as old as AS/400 support access via JDBC.  Client Access has an ODBC driver or one can use JT400 to talk to IBM i (the current generation of IBM midrange machines) or even AS/400.